# Does the following number-theoretic equation have any solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Does the following number-theoretic equation have any solutions for prime $p$ and positive $x$?

$$\frac{\sigma(p^x)}{p^x} = \frac{10}{9}$$

It does not have any for $x = 1$.  How about for $x > 1$?

(Note that $\sigma = \sigma_1$ is the sum-of-divisors function.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\frac{\sigma(p^x)}{p^x} =\frac{p^{x+1}-1}{p^x(p-1)}= \frac{10}{9},$then
$$9p^{x+1}-9=10p^{x+1}-10p^{x},p^x(p-10)=-9,p\mid 9,p=3,3^x\cdot7=9$$
so there is no such integer $x>1.$

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no solution. Clearly, the only hope for a solution would have to be with $p=3$ (that's the only way a $9$ is ever going to show up in the denominator). And
$$\sigma(3^x)=1+3+\cdots+3^x=\frac{1}{2}(3^{x+1}-1)$$
so
$$\frac{\sigma(3^x)}{3^x}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^x}=\frac{10}{9}$$
if and only if
$$\frac{1}{2\cdot 3^x}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{10}{9}=\frac{7}{18},$$
which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there is no solution of $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \frac{10}{9}$ for any positive integer $n$, let alone prime powers.  The ratio $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ can only have a factor of 3 in the denominator if $n$ is a multiple of 3, but then $n$ has both $n$ and $n/3$ as divisors, so
$$
\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} \ge \frac{n + n/3}{n} = \frac{4}{3} > \frac{10}{9}.
$$